# <script> causing problem with XML tag name mismatch

Tags: javascript, xml, tags, mismatch

In attempting to work with a test page for making some jquery getJSON calls I get errors which show up in the error console of Firefox:

```
XML tag name mismatch (expected input)
http://localhost:8080/<MyApp>/jquery-1.4.4.js
</body>

XML tag name mismatch (expected input)
http://localhost:8080/<MyApp>/json.js
</body>

The original html has the following:

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Application</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/<MyApp>/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/<MyApp>/json.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Application</h1>
    <p>
    <label id="heartbeatLabel">Gateway Heartbeat:</label>
    <input id="heartbeatStatus" type="text" readonly="true" width="30">
    <input id="jsRunning" type="text" readonly="true" width="30">
    <input id="btnHeartbeat" type="button" value="Test Heartbeat" onclick="javascript:testHeartbeat();">
  </body>
```

Firebug tells me that the javascript scripts were both found and the Net panel gives a status of 200.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The `<p>` tag is not closed, and neither is the `<html>` tag (unless you missed it when you copy/pasted). I don't think that's the cause of the error, but it should be fixed nonetheless. Also, the `<input>` tags should be self-closed: `<input id="..." />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is invalid:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/<MyApp>/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
```

It's not allowed to have `<` and `>` in attributes. You have to escape these characters, although that wouldn't solve your problem, because I'm not sure where `<MyApp>` comes from.

Comment: I think he's just anonymized his application name after copy/pasting the code - but if his app somehow _is_ called `<MyApp>`, then you're right...

Comment: I was just anonymizing the path.  I should have just put MyApp in place.

Comment: The @RequestMapping had been improperly set to "/*" so that if it could not find the javascript files jquery and json it would read the main page as the return result which of course was not in the right format.  Thanks for your responses